# Will XGBoost early stopping stop after marginal improvements?

Tags: machine-learning, xgboost, early-stopping

I know that early stopping will happen if we don't have any improvement (or drop in performance) in the last X rounds. i.e. we need at least one round in the last X with little improvement, in order to continue.

But I read here:
https://www.kaggle.com/vincentf/early-stopping-for-xgboost-python the following in-code comment:

```
stops 50 iterations after marginal improvements or drop in performance on your hold out set
```

1. So, it seems that `marginal improvements` is like `no improvement`, is it right ?
2. If so, what is the value of `marginal improvements` ? Can we set it's value ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The meaning of "*marginal improvements*" in the post you have linked to is quite unclear (and arguably misleading); here is the relevant information from the [documentation](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/python/python_api.html#xgboost.train):

> **early_stopping_rounds** (int) – Activates early stopping. Validation metric needs to improve at least once in every **early_stopping_rounds** round(s) to continue training.

which clearly does not support the "*marginal improvements*" claim.